# merge lines into custom lines

Tags: text-processing

Input:

```
ID   Name   NUMBER

1ABC234)234-2345,

2CBF23588900,

3knl334235354,

4gkmnk436563654,
```

Desired Output:

```
    *ID   Name   NUMBER            ID   Name   NUMBER       ID   Name   NUMBER*
LINE--1    1ABC234)234-2345,2CBF23588900,3knl334235354,
LINE--2    4gkmn436563654,5JNKN53546536,6jknk5643545645,
LINE--3    7........,8..........,9............,
LINE--4    10.........,11.......,12...........
```

I tried using this command but unfortuantely it gives me everything into single line

```
tr -d '\n'<sample.txt
```

But I need to generate file with exactly like I said above with unix command.

Comment: why your header line is duplicating? is there empty lines between each lines and it's always one empty line? Why the last line has not ended with _Comma_? what does that _dots_ means? does the lines in input are sorted and follow numerical prefix order and in output those numbers are there or those are coming from somewhere else that script should generate? please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/391806/edit)  your question and clarify these details. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would like to merge the lines is such a way that each new line contains three of the lines from the input file and that you want to keep the same header:

```
$ ( head -n 1 file; sed '1d' file | paste -d '\0' - - - ) >newfile
$ cat newfile
ID   Name   NUMBER
1ABC234)234-2345,2CBF23588900,3knl334235354,
4gkmnk436563654,line5,line6,
line7,line8,line9,
```

The input file I used was

```
ID   Name   NUMBER
1ABC234)234-2345,
2CBF23588900,
3knl334235354,
4gkmnk436563654,
line5,
line6,
line7,
line8,
line9,
```

The `head` command simply outputs the header from the file, while the `sed` and `paste` pipeline distributes the remaining lines in groups of three without inserting any delimiter. The output from both `head` and the pipeline is then redirected to a new file.

If you need the specific header that you mentioned, just replace the complete `head` command with `echo 'insert header text here'`.

If you need the `LINE--1` etc. for each line, pass the result of `paste` through `awk '{ print "LINE--" NR, $0 }'`:

```
$ ( head -n 1 file; sed '1d' file | paste -d '\0' - - - | awk '{ print "LINE--" NR, $0 }') >newfile    
$ cat newfile
ID   Name   NUMBER
LINE--1 1ABC234)234-2345,2CBF23588900,3knl334235354,
LINE--2 4gkmnk436563654,line5,line6,
LINE--3 line7,line8,
```